# Read an url HTTPS in a JSON file swift

Tags: json, swift, url, request

I try to read an URL request (in dictionary "vehicles")in a json but the array will empty
This is the json and I need to read the dictionary and the url that are in vehicles

```
{
"count": 87, 
"next": "https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=2", 
"previous": null, 
"results": [
    {
        "name": "Luke Skywalker", 
        "height": "172", 
        "mass": "77", 
        "hair_color": "blond", 
        "skin_color": "fair", 
        "eye_color": "blue", 
        "birth_year": "19BBY", 
        "gender": "male", 
        "homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/", 
        "films": [
            "https://swapi.co/api/films/2/", 
            "https://swapi.co/api/films/6/", 
            "https://swapi.co/api/films/3/", 
            "https://swapi.co/api/films/1/", 
            "https://swapi.co/api/films/7/"
        ], 
        "species": [
            "https://swapi.co/api/species/1/"
        ], 
        "vehicles": [
            "https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/14/", 
            "https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/30/"
        ],
```

This is the code that I try

```
if let results = json["results"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {

                    var finalArray2 : [String] = []
                    for result in results {
                        if let dict = result as? [String: Any], let vehicles = dict["vehicles"] as? String{
                            self.URLveicoli = vehicles
                            //print(self.nomepersonaggio)
                            print(self.URLveicoli)
                            //finalArray.append(name)
                            finalArray2.append(vehicles)

                        }
                    }
                    print(finalArray2)

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In json `vehicles` is an array of strings (urls) not a string.

Change this

```
let vehicles = dict["vehicles"] as? String
```

To

```
let vehicles = dict["vehicles"] as? [String]
```

And to append array of vechicles

```
finalArray2.append(contentsOf: vehicles)
```

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: To append an array to an array use `append(contentsOf:)` method.